# WebSockets with ws: Client closed or server closed?

Tags: websocket, ws

In the ws Node.js WebSocket library, regarding the event `socket.on('close', ...)`, is there any **direct** way (i. e. by inspecting the event) to determine if the client has closed the socket OR the server closed it for this client?

Even when the server explicitly sets a specific close code (4001), the handler on the server side for the close event gets a generic close code (1005).

So there is no way around but to remember it somewhere if the server closed the socket?

Answer (score 2):

If the client closed it, it knows it closed it. But if it doesn't then it must be server. The same thing can happen server-side

Comment: But how does the handler for the close event know it? The handler gets called regardless. So it seems it must be remembered somewhere else.

Comment: from everywhere in the client code, wherever the connection can/will be closed, just put this line of code somewhere below it: localstorage["closedBY"] = "client" (may defer language to language)